# In jquery php application I want to route using angularjs

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs

In jquery php application I want to route using angularjs at first when load this application bootstrap carousel work but after clicking any tab of manu then carousel didnot work.how can i solve this.
**This is my index page**

```
        <!doctype html>
<html >
<head>
    <script src="file/JQuery1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="file/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="file/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="file/css/custom.css" re="stylesheet">
    <link href="file/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link href="file/css/memenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file/js/memenu.js"></script>
    <script defer src="file/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file/js/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>     
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file/css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="file/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="file/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="file/angular-resource.js"></script>
```

var app = angular.module("green_heaven",["ngRoute"])

    .config(function ($routeProvider){


            $routeProvider.when("/about",{
                templateUrl: "about.php"
                })
            $routeProvider.when("/contact",{
                templateUrl: "contact.php"
                })

            $routeProvider.when("/equipment",{
                templateUrl: "equipment.php"
                })

            $routeProvider.otherwise({
                templateUrl: "home_page.php"
                });
        });

```
</head>
<body ng-app="green_heaven">
   <div class="top_bg">
        <!--header content-->
    </div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">   
              <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#/equipment" >Equipment</a> 
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#/about">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#/contact" >Contact</a>
              </li>  
          </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
</nav>
```

Previous
            
            
              
              Next

```
<!--Top footer Slide-->


<div class="arrivals">
     <div class="container">    
         <h3>New Arrivals</h3>
         <div class="arrival-grids">             
             <ul id="flexiselDemo1">
                 <li>
                     <a href="product.html"><img src="images/a1.jpg" alt=""/>   
                     <div class="arrival-info">
                         <h4>Fusion Black Polyester Suits</h4>
                         <p>Rs 12000</p>
                         <span class="pric1"><del>Rs 18000</del></span>
                         <span class="disc">[12% Off]</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="viw">
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>Quick View</a>
                     </div>
                     <div class="shrt">
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>Shortlist</a>
                     </div></a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href=""><img src="images/a2.jpg" alt=""/>
                        <div class="arrival-info">
                         <h4>Vogue4All White Net Gowns</h4>
                         <p>Rs 14000</p>
                         <span class="pric1"><del>Rs 15000</del></span>
                         <span class="disc">[10% Off]</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="viw">
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>Quick View</a>
                     </div>
                     <div class="shrt">
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>Shortlist</a>
                     </div></a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                     <a href="product.html"><img src="images/a3.jpg" alt=""/>   
                        <div class="arrival-info">
                         <h4>Platinum Waist Coat Set Navy</h4>
                         <p>Rs 4000</p>
                         <span class="pric1"><del>Rs 8500</del></span>
                         <span class="disc">[45% Off]</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="viw">
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>Quick View</a>
                     </div>
                     <div class="shrt">
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>Shortlist</a>
                     </div></a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                    <a href="product.html"> <img src="images/a4.jpg" alt=""/>   
                        <div class="arrival-info">
                         <h4>La Fanatise White Net Gowns</h4>
                         <p>Rs 18000</p>
                         <span class="pric1"><del>Rs 21000</del></span>
                         <span class="disc">[8% Off]</span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="viw">
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>Quick View</a>
                     </div>
                     <div class="shrt">
                        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>Shortlist</a>
                     </div></a>
                 </li>
                </ul>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                 $(window).load(function() {            
                  $("#flexiselDemo1").flexisel({
                    visibleItems: 4,
                    animationSpeed: 1000,
                    autoPlay: true,
                    autoPlaySpeed: 3000,            
                    pauseOnHover:true,
                    enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
                    responsiveBreakpoints: { 
                        portrait: { 
                            changePoint:480,
                            visibleItems: 1
                        }, 
                        landscape: { 
                            changePoint:640,
                            visibleItems: 2
                        },
                        tablet: { 
                            changePoint:768,
                            visibleItems: 3
                        }
                    }
                });
                });
                </script>            
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
<!--Top Footer Slide end-->
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Strip it out and only give us the relevant code please.

Comment: Also format your code.

Comment: Concept of laying angular on top of jQuery is completely backwards. Strongly suggest you read [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)